# Copy/paste menu EditText in ListView not working Lollipop

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-5.0-lollipop, copy-paste

In my Android application i have a `ListView` which contains multiple `EditText` fields. Normally in my application when i `LongTouch` a `EditText` the Copy/Paste menu shows up. When i am in this `ListView` and LongTouch a `EditText` the Copy/Paste menu in the actionbar shows for like 100ms and the soft keyboard does also show for some ms. It seems the keyboard is forcing the copy/paste menu to hide. Its is working in Android 4, Android 5 seems to be the problem.

Its driving me crazy. In my activity i have already defined: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` which i read on the internet. But unfortunately it isn't working. I hope anyone can point me in the right direction. I m clueless at the moment.

Comment: I have tried adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` and it worked in my nexus 4. Could you post codes of your `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

After a long search i discovered `<item name="android:background">@drawable/background_actionbar</item>` was causing the problem.